# How do I get Autofac delegate factories to work with obfuscation?

Tags: obfuscation, autofac

We're updating code to use Autofac.  We'd like to use custom delegate types to define factories instead of Func's.  But we also use an obfuscator, which renames parameters.  We'd like to tell the Autofac container to match by type instead of name as it does with Func's.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

On the official documentation of Autofac, you have this information

> By default, Autofac matches the parameters of the delegate to the parameters of the constructor by name. If you use the generic Func types, Autofac will switch to matching parameters by type.

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you customize the obfuscator to use the same name for the parameter name of the delegate and the constructor?

As mentioned, the way to do it right now is to use Func. Even if it were possible with just delegate factories, Autofac won't know what to do when there are two parameters of the same type. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28594953/3638742) my answer to a very similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.  We ended up creating a custom registration source using Autofac's source as a guide.  In our testing, if there are two parameters of the same type, it appears to fall back to order.