# Autofac Resolve using delegate factory by type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am using Autofac for IoC in my project. Due to some legacy software libraries I must pass some services to the controller that can't be resolved, and must be passed as parameter.

I've made a generic control using delegate factories like this:

```
public MyClass<TController, TInterface> {

     private delegate TController ControllerFactory(TInterface service);

     protected TController _myController;
     protected TController Controller {
         get
         {
             return _controller 
               ?? (_controller = ServiceLocator.Resolve<ControllerFactory>()
                                    .Invoke(this);
         }
     }

}
```

This works perfect, but for this to work I need the controller's service parameter name and the delegate service parameter name be the same, because as I have read, Autofac pairs the parameter BY NAME !!

I've seen you can do it by type registering the class with generic Func<>, but due to the legacy app I would need to leave "clean" registrations i.e.:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<MyController>();
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to make the delegate match the parameter by type??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know if it's possible to make the delegate match the parameter by type??

Yes, you can use predefined delegates. See dynamic instantiation section [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html).

Here's an quick example:

```
    public class ComponentFactory
    {
        private readonly Func<Dependency, Component> _componentFactory;

        public ComponentFactory(Func<Dependency, Component> componentFactory)
        {
            _componentFactory = componentFactory;
        }

        public Component Create(Dependency dependency)
        {
            return _componentFactory(dependency);
        }
    }

    public class Component
    {
        private readonly Dependency _dependency;

        public Component(Dependency dependency)
        {
            _dependency = dependency;
        }
    }

    public class Dependency
    {
    }
```

Registration + Usage

```
            var builder= new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<ComponentFactory>();
            builder.RegisterType<Component>();
            builder.RegisterType<Dependency>();

            var container = builder.Build();
            var factory = container.Resolve<ComponentFactory>();

            //Usage with typed parameters
            var component = factory.Create(new Dependency());
```

**Be warned, if you use this method, Autofac throws an exception if you try to add parameters with of the same type. Ex. `Component` has two dependencies on `Dependency`

Exception looks something like this:

> The input parameter type list
>   has duplicate types. Try registering a custom delegate type instead of
>   using a generic Func relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the input... anyway finally I couldn't implement this solution due to architectural issues in the project that I can't change for legacy compatibility reasons... but I keep it in mind for future implementations!

Answer (score 0):

Autofac is more specific about what type you register the controller as than most DI containers. It will only resolve the type by its type if you include `.AsSelf()` in the registration of the controller. Here is a module we use in our project for registering MVC controllers.

```
public class MvcModule
    : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var currentAssembly = typeof(MvcModule).Assembly;

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(currentAssembly)
            .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .AsSelf()
            .InstancePerDependency();
    }
}
```

Using this registration, you can resolve each controller by controller type.

```
var type = typeof(HomeController);
var controller = container.Resolve(type);
```

Comment: Sorry... maybe I didn't express myself quite right. My problem is resolving with delegate factories, not with registration itself... I'm trying to make a "base" class that will resolve generic controllers, but I don't want to use any special registration. The controller, of course, will be registered...